# How to change Domain name in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I have a domain controller named as ABCD.com but i have to change it to XYZ.com. And also i have secondary DC with the same as ABCD.com.

So my questions are as follows:

1. How to rename my Domain controller to XYZ.com without losing any data.
2. Also,should i change anything in my secondary DC also.

I'm a rookie in this area,so it would be good if anyone gives me steps to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While it's fairly trivial to rename a domain (use the `rendom` command, which is built into Windows 2008 and higher, and is part of a resource kit for older versions of windows) and then follow the rest of the steps outlined in [this document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208%28v=WS.10%29.aspx), there's [a lot of considerations](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1347.renaming-a-windows-server-2008-active-directory-domain-dsforum2wiki.aspx) around domain naming that can make the consequences of doing so very problematic.

The "steps" are easy but if you're a rookie you need to be very sure you understand how to carry out the rest of the process and the consequences of doing so. Don't even start the process until you're absolutely certain you understand how to finish it and what will happen. Ideally, you should try this out on a "test" copy of the domain you plan to rename prior to doing it on the live one.